# maven downloaded jars for multiple projects

Tags: java, maven

I'm learning `maven` build process.

Downloaded jar files are saved in the 
`$HOME/.m2/repository` 
(https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/#initial)

What if I use maven for multiple projects?

Does maven separate files among projects as virtual environment of python would do? (or Node.js stores packages in `node_modules` in the project folder)

Comment: Have you looked into Maven multi modules? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: Simply no it uses the same location for all projects. Based on the coordinates there is no problem with that...

Answer (score 1):

The location to which Maven downloads files (aka the local repository) is definied in the `settings.xml` file which your Maven instance is using.

If you use the *same* `settings.xml` file for each of your Maven projects then they will all share the same local repository.

By default, the `settings.xml` is resolved from ([see the docs](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)) ...

> The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
>
> A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

But you can also chose a specific `settings.xml` on the command line using the `-s` parameter. For example:

```
mvn -s /path/to/custom/settings.xml
```

So, in summary, your Maven projects will, by default, use the same local repository but you can choose a different repository per project.

Note: since the contents of the local repository are artifacts clearly identified by groupId, artifactId and version there is generally no downside to sharing a local repository amongst multiple projects.